# Union ordered by last login

Tags: mysql, union

I've tried this

`Select u from users where idU in 
((Select idU1 from friends where idU2=1) Union (Select idU2 from friends where idU1=1))`

but it doesn't work.

So, I had to do this:
`Select u from users where idU in (Select idU1 from friends where idU2=1) 
Union 
Select u from users where idU in (Select idU2 from friends where idU1=1)`

But now, I want to order those users by last login.

What could I do?  Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below.
I have wrote this by keeping in mind that `LastLogin` column is in users table

```
Select 
    u
from
    users
where
    idU in (
            Select idU1 from amistades where idU2 = 1 
            Union 
            Select idU2 from friends where idU1 = 1
            )
ORDER BY LastLogin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have more than a trivial number of rows in your tables, you will want some more speed:

```
SELECT  users.u
    FROM  
      (  SELECT  idU1 AS idU from  amistades where  idU2 = 1
            UNION
         SELECT  idU2 AS idU from  friends where  idU1 = 1 
      ) AS x
    JOIN  users ON x.idU = users.u
    ORDER BY  users.LastLogin;
```